# Angular CanDeactivate isn't working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I'm trying to use the `CanDeactivate` function in the routing but `canDeactivate` function is never called when invoked on another route.

**CanDeactivateGuard :**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements  CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate>{

  canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate) {
    return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
  }
}
```

**CatalogViewComponent :**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import {CanComponentDeactivate} from '../../can-deactivate.guard';
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  template: `
    <h1>Catalog</h1>
  `,
})
export class CatalogViewComponent implements CanComponentDeactivate{
  canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    console.log('working');  // Not Entering this function when invoked another route
    return false;
  }
}
```

**routing.module.ts :**

```
 { path: 'catalog', component: CatalogViewComponent, canDeactivate: CanDeactivateGuard },
```

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-bqtatw?file=app%2Fcan-deactivate.guard.ts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the guard as an array. (You could have more than one.)

```
{ path: 'catalog', component: CatalogViewComponent, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard] }
```

and also add the guard as a `provider`:

```
providers: [CanDeactivateGuard],
```

Comment: Does this works with load childen? as CanDeactivateGuard object shows null in my case